# what is "reading materials" in Japanese?

Tags: translation, english-to-japanese

what is "reading materials" in Japanese?

"reading materials" は日本語で何ですか？

Comment: Hello and welcome to Japanese.SE! We don't allow straight translation questions here, so please do share what you found when you tried to translate this yourself (or do it now). It would also help if you gave an example sentence.

Answer (score 3):

A possible translation is [読]{よ}み[物]{もの}.

> [読]{よ}み: reading, [物]{もの}: matter, material
>
> この[本]{ほん}は[面白]{おもしろ}い**読み物**です。*This book (reading material) is interesting*

But then there are alternatives which relies on your context. An example sentence in English would help you get some alternatives.